# Question about Final Scenes in Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-rogue-nation

During the final moments of *Mission: Impossible - Rogue Nation*:

> Ethan watches the disk they stole, revealing a list of bank account numbers and instructions to access the money. He then drills a hole through the disk to destroy the data.

He then tells the main baddie that he memorized all of the account numbers.

Is that really possible? Or was Ethan bluffing? Did he just transfer all the money into a single account/few accounts? OR was he just completely bluffing, only remembered one or two account numbers, and the rest of the money is gone now?

I don't remember the movie really addressing it, and it seems like too big of a thing to gloss over. Or I guess I should turn off my brain and just go with "Ethan is basically the strongest/most intelligent/most skillful person on the planet."

Comment: This is an interesting question because it will likely require some info from outside the film. It's possible something in a previous film explained his ability to memorize really quickly... or that there was a scene left out that explains it... or he could have been lying.

Comment: Well, I guess he just bluffed. Afterall neither he nor enyone else really need that money, only Solomon. So he learned the one account he gave. He didn't plan to reveal anything more to Lane anyway.

Comment: I don't remember how many numbers there were on the list but there exists tricks to memorize quickly numbers with about 20 digits (like an international bank account number). Also, Ethan is known to be a master for impersonating people, which implies good memory skills to remember information on these people. That of course doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I guess one thing I should mention -- I was asking this question under the assumption that he'd want to potentially try and not lose all that money. If the money doesn't matter, then this question can be answered pretty simplistically.

Comment: It's worth noting that the account number in question had a number of repeated digits.  Which made it easier to memorize, which is why he chose it.  (Unfortunately I couldn't find a screen shot of the scene in question; anybody got a copy of the movie who can find out the actual number?)

Comment: I just checked it out today: The actual information is: Bank: `ADJS Banking Ltd`, Balance: `USD $50,000,000.00`, Account Number: `3005 7111 0669`, Sort Code: `22-08-48`.  Not the easiest thing in the world to memorize, but not as difficult as if all the digits were different.  It may have been the easiest one he was able to find on such short notice.

Comment: Yes, I can do it. I can memorize 60 digits in 1 minute and once memorize 3000 digits of pi. I use memory palace.
The best memory athletes can memorize 80 numbers in 15 seconds. As far as I know, spies are also learning these methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of the film, Alan (Alec Baldwin) talking to Senate about how the IMF missions were successful only because of some LUCK.

In another scene, when Ethan goes underwater to plant the chip, he almost runs out of oxygen and is not able to think clearly. And (what it looked like) he randomly chooses one of the two identical chips and inserts it into the machine.

So, in the end, I think, he memorized just one or two account numbers and was totally **bluffing**. And as they say, fortune favors the brave!